# Regex to avoid javascript in TinyMCE richtext box

Tags: asp.net-mvc, tinymce, tinymce-5

I'm using this Regex to validate the content of a TinyMCE richtext box.  This is an MVC application and I don't want users to be able to enter malicious Javascript.

The regex is failing as the richtext box is generating its own HTML.

```
[RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z0-9\s-'.]+$", ErrorMessage = "Only letters, numbers, spaces and '-' are allowed in description.")]
```

I tried removing the regex and adding this code, but was able to enter a script tag.

```
valid_elements : "a[href|target=_blank],strong/b,div[align],br",
```